# Corona SDK: How do I open certain luage page using loop when button is pressed?

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, coronasdk

I am working on this 2D game and I am having problem with menu page. What I want to happen in the menu page is whenever a "level button" is pressed, the corresponding .lua file is open. For example when the first button is pressed level1.lua is open. I am not familiar with loops and arrays in corona sdk. Can someone help me how I may achieve this with loops because the first stage of my game has 63 levels, so it would take forever to do it manually. Thanks for your time. Below is what I have so far:

```
local touchMenu = function (event)  

   local obj = event.target         
   local bid = obj.id                           

  for a = 1, numLevels, 1 do -- loop through the number of levels set up in data.lua
        levels[a].id = a
  end

   if bid == 1 then                

        _G.nextScene = "level"..1..""
        storyboard.gotoScene("loading")   

    end
           if bid == 2 then         

        _G.nextScene = "level"..2..""
        storyboard.gotoScene("loading")   

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid global variables (_G.nextScene).
To do what you want and to deal with the global variable, you can do that :

In your menu.lua :

```
local touchMenu = function(event)
    local obj = event.target         
    local bid = obj.id
    local custom =
    { 
        nextScene = "level" .. bid
    }
    storyboard.gotoScene("loading", {params=custom})
end
```

In your loading.lua :

```
local nextScene

-- Call this function when you want
function scene:goToNextScene()
    storyboard.gotoScene(nextScene)    
end

function scene:enterScene(event)
    nextScene = event.params.nextScene
end
scene:addEventListener("enterScene")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i=1,63 do -- 63 is the number of levels
  storyboard.gotoScene("level"..i) 
  return true;
end
```

or in your case, you can already fetch the `bid`, then the following may be enough:

```
storyboard.gotoScene("level".. bid)
return true;
```

Keep coding............... :)